# database - MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have three tables Inventory, Book and DVD. Now I have to make Book and DVD as a subdatasheet to Inven[image]tory Table. Is it possible to do via query in MS Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the inventID columns in the Book/DVD tables equal the inventoryID in the inventory table then yes'ish.

If you want actual subdatasheets you wouldn't need a query, just open the inventory table and insert the subdatasheet.  The problem is you can only have one subdatasheet so you won't be able to see the Book and DVD subdatasheets together.

You can run a query but viewing both DVD and Book together will result in a weird looking query where columns for Book and DVD will show on the same line.  This is how you would write that query:

```
    SELECT Inventory.*, DVD.*, Book.*
    FROM (Inventory LEFT JOIN DVD ON Inventory.inventoryID = DVD.inventid) 
    LEFT JOIN Book ON Inventory.inventoryID = Book.inventID;
```

It would output like this:

[Sample query (I didn't create all the fields)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR4Pm.png)

In the example, Test 1, 2 and 3 are books and 4 and 5 are DVD's

You might be better served to just make separate inventory tables for both types of items and get rid of the inventory table all together.  When you want to see it all together you can run a Union query that brings both tables together and only show the common fields (everything that's currently in the Inventory table.